# Can no longer run Blazor application without Visual Studio after upgrade to .NET 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-5, asp.net-blazor

I have recently upgraded a set of Blazor (ASP.NET Core–hosted WebAssembly) projects from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5.0. After having done this, I noticed I can no longer simply run the compiled executable and navigate to the localhost:xxxx address in the browser to use my application. Yet, when I run or debug my application from Visual Studio, it works fine.

I can get a similar situation by simply creating a new .NET 5.0 ASP.NET Core–hosted Blazor WebAssembly App from the template, building it, running the executable in the server project's bin folder from Windows Explorer and trying to navigate to the address (localhost:xxxx) in the browser. Curiously, the same thing seems to happen when I create it in .NET Core 3.1.

When I use the browser to navigate to localhost:xxxx, I get a 404 on the https address and get redirected to https from http even when I have unchecked Enable SSL in the reproduction solution. I also get the 404 when I use the https address to try to navigate to my application (which at the moment has SSL disabled), but I get an ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE when I try to navigate to the http address. On the other hand, calls to a subaddress that hit the API (localhost:xxxx/api/Foo/Get) will work, though only for https.

I have trusted the self-signed certificate, so that at least isn't the problem.

What has changed or am I now doing wrong?

Comment: I guess your blazor app is consuming data from api, and api is working on https. that said blazor are trying to call your http end  point that is not accessible, there for change it to https and it should work.

Comment: Does calling "dotnet run" result in success?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ Interestingly, the Client project of my application had SSL disabled and the server project enabled, whereas in the reproduction solution it was the way around. However, turning it on in all projects makes no difference.

Comment: @rdmptn Running `dotnet "Projectdir/bin/Release/Project.exe"` results in the same problem as running the executable without using the command line. But running `dotnet run --project "Projectdir/Project.csproj"` does work, letting me navigate to my application! What does that mean?

Comment: Make sure you have the runtime installed, try repairing the dotnet installation.  I'm also running out of ideas

Comment: @rdmptn I've got AspnetCore.All, AspNetCore.App, NETCoreApp, and WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.1 runtime (and a number of non-5.0.1 runtimes) installed. Repairing the Visual Studio installation had no effect; is there any other way to try to repair the dotnet installation? Could IIS Express have something to do with it? Maybe like it being required to pick up that the executable starts up, but that this is no longer happening?)

Comment: Run the donet installer again to repair or reinstall, run the installer for the runtime too.

Comment: @rdmptn I've run several installers. If I run the dotnet SDK 5.0.101 installer it will install it just fine, but will give a 0x80070643 error during repair. Does that mean anything to you? Could it make any difference to run the executable from a Docker container?

Comment: I don't know, sorry